# Javascript program running for ever in all browser

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I have below code to generate permutation of given number. The problem is if i try to generate permutation above 5 digit then its running for ever. How to optimize this program to get the result displayed in browser.

```
<html>
<script>



function permute(level,  permuted, used,  original) {
    var length = original.length;
    if (level == length) {
        //System.out.println(permuted);
        document.getElementById("nmbrs").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nmbrs").innerHTML + "<br />" +permuted
    } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (!used[i]) {
                    used[i] = true;
                    permute(level + 1, permuted + original[i],
                       used, original);
                    used[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }



function executeP(){
    var s = ['0','1','2','7'];
    document.getElementById("nmbrs").innerHTML = "";
    var length = eval(document.getElementById("num").value);

    /*for(var i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
        var used = [false, false, false, false];
        permute(i, "", used, s);
    }*/

    var newArray = ['0','1','2','7'];
    if(length > 4){

        var newIte = length - 4;
        do{
            newArray.push(s[(newIte-1) % 4]);
            newIte--;
        }while(newIte>0);
    }

    var used = [false, false, false, false,false, false, false, false,false, false, false, false];
    permute(newArray.length-length, "", used, newArray);

}


</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num" />
<input type="button" value="Generate Num" onclick="executeP()" />

<div id="nmbrs" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you're constantly manipulating the DOM, which is expensive.  Instead, store the results in a temporary location, and then generate the HTML you want to use, and only then append it to the DOM.

This is a modified version of your page / script that shows what I mean, and generates permutations of length 8+ easily;

```
<html>
<script>
var results = [];

function permute(level, permuted, used, original) {
    var length = original.length;
    if (level == length) {
        results.push(permuted);
    } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (!used[i]) {
                    used[i] = true;
                    permute(level + 1, permuted + original[i],
                       used, original);
                    used[i] = false;
                }
            }
    }
}

function executeP(){
    var s = ['0','1','2','7'];
    document.getElementById("nmbrs").innerHTML = "";
    var length = eval(document.getElementById("num").value);

    var newArray = ['0','1','2','7'];
    if(length > 4) {

        var newIte = length - 4;
        do {
            newArray.push(s[(newIte-1) % 4]);
            newIte--;
        } while (newIte>0);
    }

    var used = [false, false, false, false,false, false, false, false,false, false, false, false];
    permute(newArray.length-length, "", used, newArray);
    var resultHtml = "";
    var resultLength = results.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
        resultHtml += results[i];
        resultHtml += "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("nmbrs").innerHTML = resultHtml;
}

</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num" />
<input type="button" value="Generate Num" onclick="executeP()" />
<div id="nmbrs" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for your solution. But why till 8? I am trying to generate n digit

Comment: Well, the recursion that @user393001 brings up certainly isn't helping.  Also, at that length the numbers start to get huge.  There are n! permutations of length n, so at 8 you have 40320 8-digit numbers that you're generating and adding to the page.  At 9, you have 362880, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion is going to keep everything on the stack. You either need to somehow make it tail recursive (remove the recursive call from the loop and move it to the end of the function somehow) or push all the recursive calls to your own stack so you can at least let the functions die. All this assumes that the browser is smart enough to detect it being tail recursive too, so good luck with IE.

Comment: All i was wondering is, it is giving instant result while i run thru JAVA. But its not working in browser

Comment: Java manages the heap completely differently and has the JVM which may be tuning it for you. Java also can have allot more memory to work with so you wont hit the resource issues (which I suspect is the problem here) with the same amount of calls.